# Using WinRAR to compress a folder stucture

Tags: zip, winrar, command-line

I am trying to zip up the following directory contents:

```
C:\Test\*.*
C:\Test\bin\*.*
```

I want to be able to zip up the `Test` directory and the `bin` subdirectory, however, I need the `Test` directory’s contents to be the root of the archive.

Using the WinRAR command-line program (rar.exe), I tried this command:

```
"C:\File.zip" -ep "C:\Test"
```

However, this puts all the folder contents in root of the archive. I also tried the following command, but got the same results:

```
"C:\File.zip" -ep "C:\Test\*.*" "C:\Test\bin"
```

How can I get the results I’m trying to achieve?

Comment: r is the switch for recursive

Comment: x and x@ allow you to disallow files

Comment: @aking, the `-r` switch will also add everything else that is in `C:\Test`, which Lee has not said is desired.

Answer (score 4):

You are using the `-ep` switch which **`Exclude[s] paths from names`**. If paths are not stored, then all files go in the root.

To get `C:\Test` to be treated as the root of the archive, you need to run the compression from inside the directory.

Use this instead:

```
C:\>cd Test

C:\Test>:: then, either
C:\Test>rar a "C:\File.zip" "*.*" "bin\*.*"

C:\Test>:: or
C:\Test>rar a "C:\File.zip" "*.*" "bin"
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by:

```
rar a -ep1 -r "C:\File.zip" "." "bin\*.*"
```

-ep1 = Do not store the path entered at the command line in archive. Exclude base folder from names.

-r: recurses subfolders

It worked for me!

http://comptb.cects.com/2503-using-the-winrar-command-line-tools-in-windows
http://www.qa.downappz.com/questions/winrar-command-line-to-add-files-with-relative-path-only.html

Comment: Links are dead. Try https://documentation.help/WinRAR/HELPSwEP1.htm